# how to download posts data(images/videos) from instagram with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, backend, instagram

I want to download images from a public Instagram profile sorted by number of likes on that post using `python3`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with instaloader package

```
pip install instaloader
```

try below snippet to download posts data(images/videos/caption) from a public profile.

```
from instaloader import Instaloader, Profile 
L = Instaloader()
PROFILE = "insta_username" #instagram username for profile you want to download data
profile = Profile.from_username(L.context, PROFILE)
posts_sorted_by_likes = sorted(profile.get_posts(), key=lambda post: post.likes,reverse=True)
selected_range = posts_sorted_by_likes[0:2] #to download from only 2 posts
for post in selected_range:
    L.download_post(post, PROFILE)
```